# clicking the lock into place

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "clicking the lock into place" in regard to a bicycle mean "to lock the bicycle"?

> A cyclist rattles by and I watch as the youngster riding it pulls up
>   alongside the Memorial to the 65,000 Murdered Austrian Jews, hitches
>   it up on to its stand, clicks the lock into place and disappears
>   through a doorway. Somewhere to park your bike, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means "closing, ie locking, the lock".  One would assume that the lock is around both a part of the bicycle and the stand, but this is only an assumption that the lock has been used correctly.  The text could legitimately continue thus:

*A cyclist rattles by and I watch as the youngster riding it pulls up alongside the square, hitches it up on to its stand, clicks the lock into place and disappears through a doorway.  On closer inspection, I notice that she has only locked the rear wheel to the frame of the bike, and not to the stand.  I decide to steal the bike, and walk off, carrying it."*

BTW, the original text contains an error: in "the youngster riding it", "it" is presumably a bicycle, but there has been no mention of a bicycle, only a **cyclist**.  Taken at face value, this suggests that the youngster is riding a cyclist, not a bicycle, which almost certainly wasn't what was intended.

Comment: Hi @Max Williams  I just found and  replaced the original context. Does " stand" here mean one of those iron stands that exist in the streets to lock your bicycle to ? Or does it mean the concrete dais existing under this memorial installation in the square?

Comment: @user127733 - It's quite ambiguous, though it implies that the "stand" is somehow a part of the memorial.

Comment: The quotation ise from a book called Art and the City by Nicholas Whybrow. In the text you can tell this happens in the Judenplatz, Vienna. In my experience integral rear wheel locks are quite common in continental europe as are integral bike stands. Streetview doesn't show bike racks in the square, though you can see a bike propped on its own stand  https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Judenpl.,+1010+Wien,+Austria/@48.2115568,16.3697306,78m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x476d07a289dfd449:0x47a380d0921ef928!8m2!3d48.2115267!4d16.3695306?hl=en So flipping down a stand and clicking a lock works.

Comment: The quote in context is here https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=36j3AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT166&ots=X2LMPlKu-W&dq=cyclist%20rattles%20by%20and%20I%20watch%20as%20the%20youngster%20riding%20it%20pulls%20up%20alongside%20the%20square&pg=PT166#v=onepage&q=cyclist%20rattles%20by%20and%20I%20watch%20as%20the%20youngster%20riding%20it%20pulls%20up%20alongside%20the%20square&f=false

Comment: @HotLicks "hitches *it* up on to *its* stand" sounds very much to me as if the stand is an integral part of the bicycle, as Spargirl has suggested.  I remember bikes with integral fold-down legs or stands when I was younger - we don't know the date of the article.

Comment: @TrevorD I assumed it was a metal ring/tube attached to the pavement for bikes to be locked up to, but you're right, they may have meant the bike's own stand.  My bike has one of these, I've never used it.

Comment: @TrevorD - Like I said, it's ambiguous.

Comment: @TrevorD if it helps, the book is dated 2010. The Streetview image in the square is a bizarrely close match to the article description. There is a large  free standing plaque off to the side of the Square, which presumably tells about the monument, a bike is parked in front of the plaque, hitched up on its own stand. I like to think it's the same person who cycles to work in the cafe every day since 2010!

Comment: @Spagirl - The free-standing plaque appears to be relatively new, and appears to have been designed to prevent the locking of bicycles to it.  One wonders if it replaced an earlier one that was not so designed.